# using arithmetic comparison as a precondition in PDDL

Tags: comparison, pddl

I was looking for a way to set a comparison as a precondition to an action in PDDL. Is there a way to say for example:

```
(:functions (goal))    

(:action CheckLoser  
    :parameters  (?team)  
    :precondition  
        (> goals 5)  
    :effect  
        (loses ?team)  
)
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that i am currently using fast downward, and apparently it doesn't allow this type of  predicates. Is there a planner that does??

Comment: I don't know if PPDDL has anything to do with all this, maybe. But i haven't been able to find a PPDDL planner.

Answer (score 1):

Fast Downward doesn't support using an arithmetic comparison as an action precondition, but the planner **Metric-FF** does. The latter can be downloaded from [here](https://fai.cs.uni-saarland.de/hoffmann/metric-ff.html), and it is easy to install:

- ensure `flex` and `bison` are installed on your system; On Ubuntu just use:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install bison flex
  ```
- run `make` in the source directory

`Metric-FF` can be executed as follows :

```
./ff -o path/to/domain.pddl -f path/to/problem.pddl
```

---

To solve the problem in the question, I used a variable `cost` to track the time and allowed an *action* to occur after a certain amount of time has passed.

My code sample is as follows:

- Define a `:predicate` in the *domain file*, e.g. `(cost ?cost)`
- Define a `:function` in the *domain file*, e.g. `(:functions (total-cost ?cost))`
- Add `(cost)` in the `:objects` part of the *problem file*
- In the `:init` part of the *problem file*, set the *"time"* to start as *"x"*, e.g. `(= (total-cost ?cost) 0)` where *"time"* is `cost` and *"x"* is equal to `0`.
- Now it is possible to use the arithmetic comparison in any action precondition; e.g. `(> (total-cost ?cost) x)`, where `x` can be set to any value (including floating point numbers); Note that in this case `?cost` must be included in the `:parameters` section of the said action
- Finally, the value of `total-cost` can be increased *(resp. decreased)* after every action execution with `(increase (total-cost ?cost) x)` *(resp. `(decrease (total-cost ?cost) x)`)*, where `x` can again be replace with any value.

Answer (score 0):

In PDDL you cannot compare directly, Instead you can define some boolean function with parameters. Specification of such function in precondition means that the function holds true.
eg:

```
(operation
 makebigger
  (params
   (<a> Object) (<b> Object))
  (preconds
    (greater <a> <b>))
   effects
    (greater <b> <a>)))
```

Something like greater function(written in preorder). Such boolean function that states a precondition will be used in your planning.